# I've installed Unbuntu Mate 20.04 but hard drive keeps running

Tags: hard-drive, mate

I've installed Ubuntu Mate 20.04 and after starting it it reaches a point where the hard drive keeps running and the computer freezes. This is a laptop install so the only way to stop is to press the on/ off key. I've tried to update Ubuntu Mate but with no luck, the hard starts running and will not stop running until I shut it down.

Please help and thanks,
Ed Richey

Comment: What is "Ubuntu Mate 2004"?

Comment: Welcome, what do you mean by "the hard drive keeps running"? Are you hearing a noise?

Comment: There is no noise, just the light for the hard drive comes on and the computer freezes.

Comment: This is a new computer? If not, didn't happen before?

Comment: No, not a new computer. Hasn't happened before install.

Comment: Found out it was the extra codecs I added during install and after install. The optional codecs were causing this. I haven't installed them and no problems.

Comment: Can you be more precise, exactly where it freeze? Is it possible to access the journalctl? otherwise try access the repair mode from the grub.